# Cell date format in excel showing datetime

Tags: vb.net, excel, date, datetime, datagridview

I have an application that can retrieves the install date and save it at a datagridview column with the format of date only.

But when I tried to export it to an excel file, even when I tried to format the cell, it still shows me datetime instead of date only for some of the data.

[image: This is how the datagridview looks like]

[image: This is how the excel file looks like]

The code for exporting is shown below. btw I'm using vb.net

```
'reportFile : True = IE_Version_Report.xlsx      False = Data.xlsx
Sub ExportData(reportFile)
    Dim dSet As New DataSet
    dSet.Tables.Add()
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        dSet.Tables(0).Columns.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText)
    Next

    Dim dr As DataRow

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        dr = dSet.Tables(0).NewRow
        For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            dr(j) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
        Next
        dSet.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    Dim Ex As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim Wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim Ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    Ex = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Wb = Ex.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    Ws = Wb.Sheets("sheet1")

    Dim dt As DataTable = dSet.Tables(0)
    Dim col, row As Integer
    Dim rawData(dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count - 1) As Object

    For col = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        rawData(0, col) = dt.Columns(col).ColumnName.ToUpper
    Next

    For col = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        For row = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            rawData(row + 1, col) = dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(col)
        Next
    Next
    Dim finalColLetter As String = String.Empty
    finalColLetter = ExcelColName(dt.Columns.Count)

    Dim excelRange As String = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, dt.Rows.Count + 1)

    Ws.Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData
    Ws.Range("A1:L1").EntireColumn.AutoFit() 'columns in excel file will autofit according to the data

    Dim num As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1

    'set the format for dates in these few columns
    Ws.Range("D2:D" & num).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Ws.Range("F2:F" & num).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Ws.Range("H2:H" & num).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Ws.Range("J2:J" & num).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Ws.Range("L2:L" & num).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"


    Ws = Nothing

    If reportFile = True Then
        fileExported = True
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FolderPath & "\MSOffice_Report.xlsx") Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(FolderPath & "\MSOffice_Report.xlsx")
        End If
        Wb.SaveAs(FolderPath & "\MSOffice_Report.xlsx")
    Else
        fileExported = False
        If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Install\MSData.xlsx") Then
            System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Install\MSData.xlsx")
        End If
        Wb.SaveAs("C:\Install\MSData.xlsx")
        SetAttr("C:\Install\MSData.xlsx", vbHidden)
    End If

    Wb.Close(True)
    Wb = Nothing
    Ex.Quit()
    Ex = Nothing
    GC.Collect()

End Sub

Public Function ExcelColName(ByVal Col As Integer) As String
    If Col < 0 And Col > 256 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Argument", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Return Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim i As Int16
    Dim r As Int16
    Dim S As String
    If Col <= 26 Then
        S = Chr(Col + 64)
    Else
        r = Col Mod 26
        i = System.Math.Floor(Col / 26)
        If r = 0 Then
            r = 26
            i = i - 1
        End If
        S = Chr(i + 64) & Chr(r + 64)
    End If
    ExcelColName = S
End Function
```

Sorry if it's a very stupid question but I really don't know what's wrong with it.

Thanks!

Comment: You are sending all the values to Excel as strings.  The Excel entries appearing with the time component are being store in Excel as the received strings.  Notice that they are left aligned and the date-only entries are right aligned.  `11/11/1111` is an invalid Excel date value, so it can not be converted to a date value. Strings that can be interpreted in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format will be converted to a date by Excel, but you want them to be interpreted against the `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Comment: Hit the comment character limit.  Your best bet is to parse the DGV value to a DateTime value and load that into the`Object` array you are assigning to the Excel Range.  Interop will then handle the valid dates for you.  The invalid dates will still be a problem.

Comment: @TnTinMn Sorry, I had my answer all composed an hour ago, but got distracted and did not post it until just now. I did not copy your comments, even though it might look that way.

Comment: I'm a BI developer and have performed this script many times. It became so boring that I created an Excel Interop wrapper. It's basic and a work in progress. It handles a good amount including formatting, but I didn't document it. It's not very difficult to pick up when you view in Object Explorer. https://zomp.co/Files.aspx?ID=zExcel

Comment: @teylyn, LOL.  No big deal.  What I posted is not a complete solution and was meant to spur a conversion.   The OP's code has a few inconsistencies that I want be addressed before posing a solution.  Also, you may have overlooked that issue of  valid `dd/mm/yyyy` dates not being interpreted correctly.

Comment: OP - Please ignore my comment above about parsing to a `DateTime`.  The fact that you are getting a string value with the time component indicates that the DGV cell value is already a `DateTime` type that is being converted to a `String` when added to the `DataColumn` with a `String` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not recognise dates earlier than 1/1/1900 and will treat a value like `11/11/1111 12:00:00 AM` as text. See how the dates are right-aligned and the text is left aligned in your screenshot?

Text will not be affected by the number formatting you apply to show only the date of the values.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you need to adjust your code to handle the text values differently. Replace them with 1/1/1900 or some such.